# How to resolve "named type" in NSubstitute?

Tags: unit-testing, unity-container, mstest, nsubstitute

I am using `IUnityContainer` for Registering the types for resolving later. 
I have registered the types as below:

```cs
// Register a "named type" mapping
container.RegisterType<IProcessHelper, FirstResponseHelper>("FirstResponseHelper");
container.RegisterType<IProcessHelper, SecondResponseHelper>("SecondResponseHelper");
```

Hence, I could able to use as below in one of my constructor:

```cs
     public Finish(
        IUnitOfWork unitOfWork   ,
        ILog logger, 
        ..........
        [Dependency("FirstResponseHelper")] IProcessHelper firstResponseHelpe,
        [Dependency("SecondResponseHelper")] IProcessHelper secondResponseHelper
      )
     {
         .........
        _firstResponseHelpe = firstResponseHelper;
        _secondResponseHelper = secondResponseHelper;
     }
```

...and would like to get it resolved using Substitute, something-like "below". But by passing the "name" => "FirstResponseHelper" is not allowed in Substitute! :(

```cs
// Trying to resolve in UnitTest, looks like below (passing name)
IProcessHelper firstResponseHelper = Substitute.For<IProcessHelper>("FirstResponseHelper")
IProcessHelper secondResponseHelper = Substitute.For<IProcessHelper>("SecondResponseHelper")
```

I need to call a method from FirstResponseHelper & SecondResponseHelper, from my UnitTest (MSTest). 
Hence, I need to get it resolved using `Substitute.For<>` for the "named type" interface.

Comment: Hi @Lakshminarayanan, maybe consider renaming the question to "How to resolve “named type” in Unity container?". I don't think this is specific to NSubstitute, but for rather for injecting any named instance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you want to register a Substitute as named registration so that you can resolve `Finish`.  If that is the case then you can use an `InjectionFactory` to return the substitute:

```cs
container.RegisterType<IProcessHelper>("FirstResponseHelper",
    new InjectionConstructor(c => Substitute.For<IProcessHelper>()));

container.RegisterType<IProcessHelper>("SecondResponseHelper",
    new InjectionConstructor(c => Substitute.For<IProcessHelper>()));
```

As an aside I wouldn't use the `[DependencyAttribute]` and instead remove those attributes and define an `InjectionConstructor` that passes in the correct dependencies:

```cs
container.RegisterType<Finish>(
    new InjectionConstructor(
        new ResolvedParameter<IUnitOfWork>(),
        new ResolvedParameter<ILog>(),
        new ResolvedParameter<IProcessHelper>("FirstResponseHelper"),
        new ResolvedParameter<IProcessHelper>("SecondResponseHelper")));
```

or an `InjectionFactory` that does something similar:

```cs
container.RegisterType<Finish>(
    new InjectionFactory(c =>
    {
        return new Finish(c.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>(),
            c.Resolve<ILog>(),
            c.Resolve<IProcessHelper>("FirstResponseHelper"),
            c.Resolve<IProcessHelper>("SecondResponseHelper")
    }));
```